# Router.navigate doesn't work in angular app

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following code to perform http PUT:

```
updateProduct(form: any) {
  this.productService.updateProduct(form, this.id).subscribe(
    (data: any) => data
  );
  this.route.navigate(['']);
}
```

**service.ts:**

```
 updateProducts(productForm, id) {


  const temp = {
        'description': productForm.description,
        'quality': productForm.quality
    };
    return this.httpObj.put(`${this.uri}/products/${id}`, JSON.stringify(temp), {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
});
}
```

The problem is that I am able to perform the update operation but the submit button doesn't route to the home route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the router.navigate within the subscribe,

```
updateProduct(form: any) {
  this.productService.updateProduct(form, this.id).subscribe((data: any) => (
     this.route.navigate(['']);
 )};
};
```